# Mist- Couldn't connect to node? See logs for more:

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, wallets

I was trying to launch Mist after a long time and I was hit bye error popup stating:

> Couldn't connect to node? See logs for more: Node Type: geth Network:
>   main Platform: linux (Architecture x64)
>
> ..flag provided but not defined:-support-dao-fork

[image]

Have never faced the issue. I have been using the same wallet (v0.8.6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade Ethereum Wallet to [0.8.9](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases/tag/v0.8.9). Ethereum Wallet 0.8.9 will download the correct version of `geth` - see https://github.com/ethereum/mist/blob/v0.8.9/clientBinaries.json .

The newer versions of `geth` have removed the `-support-dao-fork` command line option.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that. But I am concerned about How I was able to launch the same wallet with including any additional command line option and it was working fab. Now, what's the issue?

Comment: You probably upgraded your version of `geth` and the newer version had the `-support-dao-fork` removed. When you run the old version of Ethereum Wallet, it passes this `-support-dao-fork` parameter to `geth` and it causes an error when starting `geth`.

Comment: I have not downloaded geth explicitly. I have `geth1.4.18` that came along with `Ethereum-wallet-0.8.6`. So was not expecting such behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Removing all the files from C:\Users\Your name\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum\geth\chaindata and/or from C:\Users\Your name\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum\geth\lightchaindata and starting it again solved the problem for me.